# Kivy accessing dynamically created TextInput inside a GridLayout

Tags: python, kivy

I'm relatively new to Kivy/Python/Programming. So I apologize if anything is unclear but here is my issue: I've been working on a Kivy exercise program that either randomly selects or I can manually select exercises I want to do for a workout.

The issue I'm running into now is during the manual selection of exercises (in the EditWorkoutScreen below, just click the button on the main screen to get there).  The relevant parts of my code below displays pretty much what I want (which as of now consists of labels and a text input inside a ScrollView/GridLayout) but I'm having trouble figuring out how to access the text inside the text input.  That text represents the default duration of each exercise and I'd like to be able to change that time (say if I wanted to do a particular exercise for longer/shorter during a workout). I have an on_text_validate function which prints what is in the text input but obviously right now it only returns the last row as the variables get overwritten for each row, but what I need is for each text input to be paired with the appropriate exercise.  I've tried messing around with RecycleView as it seems like that would be a good option but I've still run into issues when trying to get the text from dynamically created widgets.

So my main question is, how can I get access to each exercise's text input from these dynamically created widgets?

**wotester.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
import pandas as pd


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

exercisedict = {'exercise':['Pushups', 'Squats', 'Curls'],'focus':['Chest','Legs','Arms'],'equip':['None','None','Dumbells'], 'deftime':['30','30','40']}
exercisedf = pd.DataFrame(exercisedict)

class EditWorkoutScreen(Screen):

    def setupscreen(self):
        global exercisedf

        for index, row in exercisedf.iterrows():
            def testtext(self):
                print extime.text
            grid = GridLayout(rows=1, spacing=2)
            exname = Label(text=str(row.exercise))
            exfocus = Label(text=str(row.focus))
            exequip = Label(text=str(row.equip))
            extime = TextInput(text=str(row.deftime), size_hint=(None,None), size=(25,30),font_size=11, multiline=False)
            extime.bind(on_text_validate=testtext)

            grid.add_widget(exname)
            grid.add_widget(exfocus)
            grid.add_widget(exequip)
            grid.add_widget(extime)

            self.ids.exercisestoverify.add_widget(grid)


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("wotester.kv")


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return presentation


MainApp().run()
```

**wotester.kv**

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#: import main wotester

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    EditWorkoutScreen:

####### Layout Outlines #############################################################
<GridLayout>:
    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgb: 1,0,0
        Line:
            rectangle: self.x+1,self.y+1,self.width-1,self.height-1
        Color:
            rgb: 1,1,1

<FloatLayout>:
    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgb: 1,0,0
        Line:
            rectangle: self.x+1,self.y+1,self.width-1,self.height-1
        Color:
            rgb: 1,1,1
<BoxLayout>:
    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgb: 1,0,0
        Line:
            rectangle: self.x+1,self.y+1,self.width-1,self.height-1
        Color:
            rgb: 1,1,1
#########################################################################################


<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    FloatLayout:
        id: test
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 1, .5
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        Label:
            text: "Workout Creator"
            pos_hint:{"x": 0, "y": .4}
            font_size: 40
        Label:
            text: "Welcome"
            pos_hint:{"x": -.4, "y": .4}
            font_size: 20
        Button:
            text: "Click here"
            color: 0,1,0,1
            size_hint: .2, .1 
            pos_hint: {"x":.4, "y":.7}
            on_release: root.manager.current = "editworkout"

<MyGrid>:

<EditWorkoutScreen>:
    name:'editworkout'
    on_enter: root.setupscreen()
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Verify/Edit Workout'
            pos: 0, 550
            font_size: 20

        ScrollView:
            pos_hint: {"x":.160, "y":-.15}
            GridLayout:
                id: exercisestoverify
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: .80
                orientation: "vertical"
                height: self.minimum_height  
                row_default_height: 30
                spacing: 0
                cols:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've made some progress in solving my problem and I think I have my code working to the point where I'll be able to apply it to my full program and have it do exactly what I need it to do (hopefully!). I made some significant changes to my .py code and just some minor changes to the kv file which I'll post here in case it helps anyone else in a similar situation.

**wotester.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
import pandas as pd

exercisedict = {'exercise':['Pushups', 'Squats', 'Curls'],'focus':['Chest','Legs','Arms'],'equip':['None','None','Dumbells'], 'deftime':['30','30','40']}
exercisedf = pd.DataFrame(exercisedict)


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class EditWorkoutScreen(Screen):

    def setupscreen(self):
        for index, row in exercisedf.iterrows():
            MyGrid(str(row.exercise),str(row.focus),str(row.equip),str(row.deftime))

    def addgrids(self):
        global grids
        for i in grids:
            print i.children
            self.ids.exercisestoverify.add_widget(i)

    def printtext(self):
        global grids
        for i in grids:
            print i.extime.text


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

grids= []
class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,exname,exfocus,exequip,extime, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        global grids
        def testtext(self):
            print self.text
        self.exname = Label(text=exname)
        self.exfocus = Label(text=exfocus)
        self.exequip = Label(text=exequip)
        self.extime = TextInput(text=extime, size_hint=(None,None), size=(25,30),font_size=11, multiline=False)
        self.extime.bind(on_text_validate=testtext)

        self.add_widget(self.exname)
        self.add_widget(self.exfocus)
        self.add_widget(self.exequip)
        self.add_widget(self.extime)

        grids.append(self)


presentation = Builder.load_file("wotester.kv")


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return presentation


MainApp().run()
```

**wotester.kv**

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#: import main wotester

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    EditWorkoutScreen:

####### Layout Outlines #############################################################
<GridLayout>:
    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgb: 1,0,0
        Line:
            rectangle: self.x+1,self.y+1,self.width-1,self.height-1
        Color:
            rgb: 1,1,1

<FloatLayout>:
    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgb: 1,0,0
        Line:
            rectangle: self.x+1,self.y+1,self.width-1,self.height-1
        Color:
            rgb: 1,1,1
<BoxLayout>:
    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgb: 1,0,0
        Line:
            rectangle: self.x+1,self.y+1,self.width-1,self.height-1
        Color:
            rgb: 1,1,1
#########################################################################################


<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    FloatLayout:
        id: test
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 1, .5
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        Label:
            text: "Workout Creator"
            pos_hint:{"x": 0, "y": .4}
            font_size: 40
        Label:
            text: "Welcome"
            pos_hint:{"x": -.4, "y": .4}
            font_size: 20
        Button:
            text: "Click here"
            color: 0,1,0,1
            size_hint: .2, .1 
            pos_hint: {"x":.4, "y":.7}
            on_release: root.manager.current = "editworkout"

<MyGrid>:
    rows: 1

<EditWorkoutScreen>:
    name:'editworkout'
    on_enter: root.setupscreen()
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Verify/Edit Workout'
            pos: 0, 550
            font_size: 20

        ScrollView:
            pos_hint: {"x":.160, "y":-.15}
            GridLayout:
                id: exercisestoverify
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: .80
                orientation: "vertical"
                height: self.minimum_height  
                row_default_height: 30
                spacing: 0
                cols:1
        Button:
            text: 'press'
            on_press: root.addgrids()
            size: 100,20
            size_hint: None,None
        Button:
            text: 'text input text'
            on_press: root.printtext()
            size: 100,20
            size_hint: None,None
            pos: 100,100
```

So now upon entering the EditWorkout Screen my setupscreen function runs which instantiates a custom GridLayout (MyGrid) for each exercise in my dataframe, which is then appended to a list (grids).  I then add each object from the grids list to the GridLayout already on the screen via the addgrids function and I am now able to get the value of each textinput from the printtext function added under the EditWorkout Screen by using the grids list to pick out which textinput I want.

The main key was to make the custom GridLayout class, initialize it with all of the variables/widgets I needed, and adding each custom object to a list so I could go through that list and grab the necessary textinput text when needed.

I imagine there could be a better way to accomplish this (perhaps with RecycleView?) so if anyone else has any ideas or suggestions please let me know!